# Invalid read/write errors by valgrind when accessing struct members

Tags: c, memory, struct, valgrind

I was trying to implement a linked list in C purely as an exercise. I have the structs defined as such:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} 
node;

typedef struct list {
    size_t size;
    node* head;
}
list;
```

Now, the functions that valgrind complains about are these:

**create()**

```
list* create() {
    // alocate memory for a new list
    list* list = malloc(sizeof(list));

    if (list != NULL) {
        list->head = NULL; // this is line 65
        list->size = 0;
    }

    // return pointer to the allocated memory
    return list;
}
```

**insert()**

```
void insert(int data, list* list) {
    if (list == NULL)
        return;

    // allocate memory for new node
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    // check if allocation was successful
    if (newNode == NULL)
        return;

    // initialize new node's data
    newNode->data = data;

    // make newNode the head of the list
    newNode->next = list->head; // this is line 88
    list->head = newNode;

    // increment size
    (list->size)++;
}
```

**destroy()**

```
void destroy(list* list) {
    if (list == NULL)
        return;

    node* current = list->head; // this is line 154
    while (current != NULL) {
        node* temp = current;
        current = current->next;
        free(temp);
    }

    free(list);
}
```

The main() is as follows:

```
int main(void) {
    list* list = create();
    insert(1, list);
    destroy(list);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what valgrind outputs:

```
==10601== 1 errors in context 1 of 4:
==10601== Invalid read of size 8
==10601==    at 0x400A33: destroy (slist.c:154)
==10601==    by 0x400AAE: main (slist.c:167)
==10601==  Address 0x51fc048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==10601==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10601==    by 0x4007C3: create (slist.c:62)
==10601==    by 0x400A93: main (slist.c:165)
==10601== 
==10601== 
==10601== 1 errors in context 2 of 4:
==10601== Invalid write of size 8
==10601==    at 0x400866: insert (slist.c:89)
==10601==    by 0x400AA5: main (slist.c:166)
==10601==  Address 0x51fc048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==10601==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10601==    by 0x4007C3: create (slist.c:62)
==10601==    by 0x400A93: main (slist.c:165)
==10601== 
==10601== 
==10601== 1 errors in context 3 of 4:
==10601== Invalid read of size 8
==10601==    at 0x400852: insert (slist.c:88)
==10601==    by 0x400AA5: main (slist.c:166)
==10601==  Address 0x51fc048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==10601==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10601==    by 0x4007C3: create (slist.c:62)
==10601==    by 0x400A93: main (slist.c:165)
==10601== 
==10601== 
==10601== 1 errors in context 4 of 4:
==10601== Invalid write of size 8
==10601==    at 0x4007DA: create (slist.c:65)
==10601==    by 0x400A93: main (slist.c:165)
==10601==  Address 0x51fc048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==10601==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10601==    by 0x4007C3: create (slist.c:62)
==10601==    by 0x400A93: main (slist.c:165)
==10601== 
==10601== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If I am understanding the output correctly, the problem seems to be the access of the `struct list` member variables. However, I don't see why accessing these variables is a problem. `malloc(sizeof(list))` should allocate enough memory for both members, so where lies the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list* list = malloc(sizeof(list));
```

Whoops!  The `list` within `sizeof` is the pointer you're declaring, not the type.  So you only `malloc`-ed enough memory for one pointer, not the struct you wanted.

Avoid shadowing a type name with a variable name.  Or if you must, use

```
list* list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here:

```
list* list = malloc(sizeof(list));
```

You have a typedef for `list` and a variable named `list`.  The `sizeof` operator is taking the size of the variable, not the type.

As a rule, don't name variables the same name as a type:

```
list* create() {
    // alocate memory for a new list
    list* mylist = malloc(sizeof(list));

    if (mylist != NULL) {
        mylist ->head = NULL;
        mylist ->size = 0;
    }

    // return pointer to the allocated memory
    return mylist ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is well-identified by [@aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252529/2410359) and [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252541/2410359)

Offering a different solution: When using `sizeof()`, use the size of the dereferenced variable and not the size of the type.

```
// some_type *ptr = malloc(sizeof (some_type));
some_type *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

Even with the shadowed type `list` and variable `list`, this works

```
list* create() {

  list* list;

  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(list)); // compiles but the needed code
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof list);  // compiles but the needed code
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof *list); // good

  // allocate memory for a new list
  list = malloc(sizeof *list);
  ...
```

prints

```
4
4
8
```